# REST RequestParam optional parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have an Interface method which can be called as below -

```
{{url}}/packageName/{{var}}/list
```

It can take in a param of type `Collection<String>` , so i can fetch specific results.

```
{{url}}/packageName/{{var}}/list?paramIds=param1&paramIds=param2
```

Now if i leave paramIds empty as below, Spring MVC creates `LinkedHashMap` , size 0 and i get no results back.

```
{{url}}/packageName/{{var}}/list?paramIds=
```

This is my annotation `@RequestParam(value = "paramIds", required = "false") Collection<String> paramIds`

I tried to get rid of `required` and use `defaultValue` but unable to set `defaultValue` to `null`.

For now i changed the annotation to `@RequestParam(value = "paramIds", defaultValue = "none")` and added code in the dao to handle "none" as null - wondering if there is a better way to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't get results you have to make your logic smarter. You should ignore the `paramIds` collection if it is empty instead of simply passing it along. So instead of checking for `none` check for an empty list.

Comment: It is quite unclear what the "problem" is.  >Now if i leave paramIds empty as below, Spring MVC creates LinkedHashMap , size 0 and i get no results back.<?  - I that the the observed behaviour? But whatis the wanted behaviour?

Comment: Thanks i added the empty list check in the dao, that was sill

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like Spring is giving you the best option, an empty list is usually better than a null.

My first choice would be to modify your DAO code to handle an empty list instead of expecting null, but assuming that's not possible, why not have a check in your controller to pass null to your DAO if the collection is empty, like:

```
if (paramsIds.isEmpty()) {
  dao.doSomething(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks i added the empty list check in the dao, that was sill